# How to write in or replace new values in a conditional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, mask

I construct an array,

```
a=np.tile(np.arange(5),4)

a
>>>array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and I set up some condition,

```
mask=a!=0
a[mask]
>>>array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

now I wanna replace the odd index elements by the even ones, and I try

```
a[mask][1::2]=a[mask][::2]
a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

but it doesn't make any change.

Answer (score 1):

[Boolean index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) returns a copy of the data instead of view. *As with index arrays, what is returned is a copy of the data, not a view as one gets with slices.* Since `a[mask]` is a copy `a[mask][1::2]` won't change the original array.

Instead of using a boolean mask, you can keep the original non zero index using `np.flatnonzero`, subset the index with odd and even positions and then do the assignment with the index:

```
a=np.tile(np.arange(5),4)
idx = np.flatnonzero(a != 0)
a[idx[1::2]] = a[idx[::2]]
a
# array([0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3])
```

Comment: thx, but I happen to use `!=0` as an example, what if the condition is different, such as `a>0` or `a!=1`, etc. then the way to use `np.flatnonzero` is not universal.

Comment: It should still work the same way. `np.flatnonzero` is checking the result of the condition which is a boolean array. So it shouldn't matter what the condition is.

Comment: thx, I find `np.flatnonzero` makes the multidimensional arrays flattened, that's not what I want. How can I fix this or any other way to handle this?

Comment: Can you give an example of multi dimensional array and how you want to transform it?

Comment: My matrix is 4d 1000*1000*1000*1000, it's become confused if I flatten the whole matrix, do you agree?